# EMC tests requirements

Tags: pcb, emc, hardware

I have designed many boards since graduation in my position as Hardware Engineer, but none of these boards tested its electromagnetic compatibility with the standards.
However in all my designs I have tried to apply all the guidelines for EMC.

I want to know how to be sure of my design that it will take the certification, what are the previous steps before taking the boards to the testing house.

Comment: That depends on the EMC requirement you're going for. But a well designed board should pass without issue. The only way to know for sure that you'll pass is to do the test. That's why you do them.

Comment: My boards are Designed for automotive applications, is there any tools I can purchase to do some of the tests.
and also how many different tests should be done on the board?

Comment: Automotive is an EMC nightmare. Every manufacturer has their own standards to test by, good luck with that. You can purchase tools to do all the tests, just google "ems test kit" and lots of people have it there. Many of these bits of kit are tens of thousands of pounds/dollars plus. It is probably best to talk to your local test house to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: If you want to set up a bench you will need spectre analyser, a LISN and a ground plan for conducted emission. Make sure the power loop is a small as possible on your PCB, Dv/dt on the switching node not too too fast, ground plan if possible, separate the power, analogue and digital ground then connected in a star point connection. input filter with CMC. try to understand the different frequency range noise. it will be a good start. Most important ask God's help

Comment: Very useful is an AM transistor radio. Place it against the DUT (device under test) and tune across the band. You'll almost certainly find signals. Increase distance slightly and note how the worst vanish )(you hope :-) ). Try it at about 2 metres. Now compare with devices of known good or bad EMC performance. FM band not as useful. | Also very useful is a television that can be manually tuned across its whole range. | I used these before SDR was a thing - nowdays a SDR tuned across the HF-VHF -UHF bands + a brain eyes and ears gives you a rough spectrum analyser.